# Error exporting the mean of an Image List (of 173 Elements)

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, export, list, reducers

I am trying to export the LST mean for a period of time. I converted the Image collection I had to a List, but I cannot calculate the mean of all the elements within the List so there is only 1 image left to export.

Also tried Reducers, but I cant get it right.. Any ideas?

```
Map.centerObject(geometry);

// Apply Cloud mask
  function maskL8sr(col) {

  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  var qa = col.select('pixel_qa');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return col.updateMask(mask);}

// Declare visualization parameters (2 sets)
var vizParams = { bands: ['B5', 'B6', 'B4'],  min: 642,  max: 3307,  gamma: [1, 0.9, 1.1]};
var vizParams2 = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],  min: 0,  max: 3000,  gamma: 1.4};

// Load Landsat Data collection for the data span declared (from 24/3/2013 up to 15/12/2021) and put them
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')

    .map(maskL8sr)

    .filterDate('2013-03-24','2021-12-15')

    .filterBounds(geometry)

    .map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)});

print('Landsat 8 Images Collection', collection);

// Calculate a Reducer that aggregates data of the image Collection called collection over time 
  var image = collection.mean();
    
  Map.addLayer(image, vizParams2,'Mean');

  // NDVI Calculation (and then find the min and max of NDVI through Reducer function)
    var ndvi1 = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');

    var ndviParams = {min: 0.10554729676864096, max: 0.41295681063122924, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};

    var col_list = collection.toList(collection.size());

    var LSTcol = col_list.map(function (ele) {

    var date = ee.Image(ele).get('system:time_start');

    var ndvi = ee.Image(ele).normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');

    var min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({

                       reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),

                       geometry: geometry,

                       scale: 30,

                        maxPixels: 1e9}).values().get(0));
  
    var max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({

                        reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),

                        geometry: geometry,

                        scale: 30,

                        maxPixels: 1e9}).values().get(0));

  // Coefficients Calculations
   var fv = (ndvi.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))).pow(ee.Number(2)).rename('FV');
   var a= ee.Number(0.004);
   var b= ee.Number(0.986);
   var EM = fv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM');
   var image = ee.Image(ele);
   var LST = image.expression(
                              '(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15',{

                              'Tb': image.select('B10').multiply(0.1),

                              'Ep': fv.multiply(a).add(b)});

             return ee.Algorithms.If(min, LST.set('system:time_start', date).float().rename('LST'), 0);
             }).removeAll([0]);

   
   LSTcol = ee.ImageCollection(LSTcol);

   print("LST_col", LSTcol);

   Map.addLayer(ndvi1, ndviParams, 'ndvi');

// Select Thermal Band 10(with brightness temperature), no calculation

var thermal= image.select('B10').multiply(0.1);
var b10Params = {min: 306.4, max: 322.8, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};

Map.addLayer(thermal, b10Params, 'thermal');

// find the min and max of NDVI

var min = ee.Number(ndvi1.reduceRegion({

  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),

  geometry: geometry,

  scale: 30,

  maxPixels: 1e9

}).values().get(0));

var max = ee.Number(ndvi1.reduceRegion({

  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),

  geometry: geometry,

  scale: 30,

  maxPixels: 1e9

}).values().get(0));

// Fractional Vegetation Equation
var fv = (ndvi1.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))).pow(ee.Number(2)).rename('FV');

//Declare Emissivity coefficients as variables
  var a= ee.Number(0.004);
  var b= ee.Number(0.986);
  var EM = fv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM');
  var imageVisParam3 = {min: 0.9865619146722164, max:0.989699971371314};
  
  Map.addLayer(EM, imageVisParam3,'EMM');

// Calculate LST through the following equations (for LST in Celsius Degree, substract -273.15)
var LST = collection.map(function (image){var date = image.get('system:time_start'); 
var LST = image.expression(
      '(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
      'Tb': thermal.select('B10'),
      'Ep':EM.select('EMM')
       }).float().rename('LST');
       return LST.set('system:time_start', date);});
      print("LSTCollection map", LST);
// Add LST image to the map
  Map.addLayer(LST, {min: 34.22748947143555, max: 50.7606086730957, palette: [
              '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
              '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
              '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
              'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
              'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003']},'LST');


// Create a List of the LST images & choose which one to export

var n = LSTcol.size().getInfo();
var imgList = LSTcol.toList(n);
print("Image List", imgList);

var img = imgList.mean() ;

Export.image.toDrive({image:img,description:'LSTmean',scale:20,folder:'GEE_Stavros',fileFormat:'GeoTIFF'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you converted to a list.  [You shouldn't do that](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#avoid_converting_to_list_unnecessarily).  You also should [not use getInfo](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server) and you should [combine your reducers](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#combine_reducers).

Just use `LSTcol.mean()` to compute the mean image and stop using lists.

Comment: I converted the collection into a List because I couldnt export the geotiff from the collection.. I tried what you suggested before and still get the same error of exporting the image into the google drive..

Comment: What error?  You haven't indicated that there is one.   Update the question.